# repeat a pandas method after every N rows

Tags: python, pandas

Here is list of tasks imported imported from kaggle homepage in pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/kaggle_unicode1.txt', encoding='utf8', sep='`', header=None)
sample=df.head(5).T
sample.columns=['task_name', 'task_description', 'task_date', 'task_prize', 'task_teams']
```

The **sample** dataframe will generate the first row correctly. I need to loop through rest of the data.
How do I repeat the transpose method for every 5 rows?

Comment: `range(5, df.shape[0], 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @jezrael points out, the data isn't uniform. sometimes there are five pieces of information, sometimes there are 6.

to clean this up and load into a dataframe you can do the following:

```
import requests as r
import pandas as pd

raw = r.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/kaggle_unicode1.txt')

# the raw data has some non ascii characters which you could likely ignore.
# and I ignore the last line if it is blank as that breaks the parsing.
data = raw.text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode()
lines = [d.strip() for d in data.split('\n')]
if lines[-1] == '':
    lines = lines[:-1]

# then split out sections of data
# this 1 lines replaces the following commented out for-loop more elegantly
blurbs = [l.split('**') for l in '**'.join(lines).split('****')]
# blurbs = []
# blurb = []
# for line in lines:
#     if line == '':
#         blurbs.append(blurb)
#         blurb = []
#     else:
#         blurb.append(line)

# it seems each section can either have 5 or 6 elements, write a function to return a uniform format record, and use pandas.DataFrame.from_records to load into dataframe

def get_record(blurb):
    if len(blurb) == 6:
        return blurb
    return blurb[:3] + [''] + blurb[3:]

cols = ['task_name', 'task_description', 'task_date', 'other', 'task_prize', 'task_teams']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([get_record(b) for b in blurbs], columns=cols)
df.head()
```

This outputs the following:

```
Out[8]:
                                          task_name  \
0  TalkingData AdTracking Fraud Detection Challenge
1        CVPR 2018 WAD Video Segmentation Challenge
2         iMaterialist Challenge (Fashion) at FGVC5
3       iMaterialist Challenge (Furniture) at FGVC5
4               Google Landmark Retrieval Challenge

                                    task_description               task_date  \
0  Can you detect fraudulent click traffic for mo...   Featured13 days to go
1  Can you segment each objects within image fram...  Research2 months to go
2          Image classification of fashion products.   Researcha month to go
3    Image Classification of Furniture & Home Goods.   Researcha month to go
4  Given an image, can you find all of the same l...   Researcha month to go

        other task_prize   task_teams
0                $25,000  3,382 teams
1                 $2,500     32 teams
2                 $2,500     67 teams
3                 $2,500    238 teams
4  image data     $2,500    129 teams
```

As you can see, the data is being properly parsed into columns. From there you can convert the types, drop the column `other`, etc. and analyze the dataset.

Comment: It seems nice, but 2 rows are bad :( `print (df[~df['task_teams'].str.endswith('teams')])`, maybe more...

Comment: thanks @jezrael, the first error is due to the dataset being wrong, it repeats the prize twice instead of mentioning number of teams. the second error is a deficiency in my code to handle boundaries, its the last row that causes this error. lemme fix the 2nd case real quick

Comment: @jezrael, the error with the last record is fixed with the updated code, I'm going to leave the treatment of the other error line to the OP, he can either drop the row from his dataset, or interploate some value for the number of teams. It is not clear to me what is the appropriate treatment for that error.

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest is use `MultiIndex`, but unfortunately data are not repeat for each 5 rows:

```
df.index = [df.index // 5, df.index % 5]
sample = df.unstack()
sample.columns=['task_name', 'task_description', 'task_date', 'task_prize', 'task_teams']
```

---

```
print (sample.head(10))

                                    task_description  \
0  Can you detect fraudulent click traffic for mo...   
1  Can you segment each objects within image fram...   
2          Image classification of fashion products.   
3    Image Classification of Furniture & Home Goods.   
4  Given an image, can you find all of the same l...   
5              Google Landmark Recognition Challenge   
6                                          289 teams   
7                                          Knowledge   
8                       image data, object detection   
9                       Getting Started2 years to go   

                                           task_date  \
0                              Featured13 days to go   
1                             Research2 months to go   
2                              Researcha month to go   
3                              Researcha month to go   
4                              Researcha month to go   
5  Label famous (and not-so-famous) landmarks in ...   
6                ImageNet Object Detection Challenge   
7                                            0 teams   
8                                          Knowledge   
9      tutorial, tabular data, binary classification   

                                      task_prize  \
0                                       $25,000    
1                                        $2,500    
2                                        $2,500    
3                                        $2,500    
4                                     image data   
5                          Researcha month to go   
6  Identify and label everyday objects in images   
7         ImageNet Object Localization Challenge   
8                                        7 teams   
9                                      Knowledge   

                                task_teams  
0                              3,382 teams  
1                                 32 teams  
2                                 67 teams  
3                                238 teams  
4                                  $2,500   
5                               image data  
6                   Research12 years to go  
7           Identify the objects in images  
8  Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster  
9                             11,169 teams
```